# Fetching rows from a function returning ref cursor dynamically

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE abc
IS
 TYPE abc_cur IS REF CURSOR;

 FUNCTION TEST
  RETURN abc_cur;
 END;
/    

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY abc
IS
FUNCTION TEST
RETURN abc_cur
IS
v_select   VARCHAR2(2000);
 BEGIN
 v_select                   := 'Select a1,a2 from pqr';
 OPEN abc_cur FOR v_select;
 RETURN abc_cur;
 END TEST;
END abc;
```

This is the dummy package that I have created, in function test select is dynamic that mean data column varies. Now my issue is that when I call this function from any other procedure or function, I get the ref cursor, then how can I fetch the data from that cursor if I don't know which column it is returning dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

If a1 and a2 are dynamic, change during runtime - you could consider using dbms_sql instead of  refcursor. [Here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:68212348056) is an example of how dynamically the rows are fetched where number of columns and their type is not known until runtime. You could change it according to your requirement.